# When does the Bestiary unlock?

Tags: heroville

I've got all blacksmith upgrades, 18 tents, 11 dungeons, and I've been playing around a day. The bestiary tab still taunts me with it's mysteries though. What do I need to do to get the Bestiary tab to unlock?

Comment: It doesn't even seem like the bestiary is implemented as the reddit makes no mention of it. nor does the code when looking through the developer console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bestiary is the 5th blueprint available it is unlocked once you have purchased all the dungeons.

The bestiary will provide you with the health and damage of all the monsters you have in your current game.

Good luck unlocking it :)

Comment: How many dungeons are there?

Comment: @fredley There are 15 dungeons.